# How can I get the metadata and exif info from a published post on Instagram in php

Tags: php, laravel, image

Here from an online exif viewer, I see that the following information can be retrieved from a published post on Instagram.

[https://www.metadata2go.com/result#j=7988e771-247c-4565-84f2-cda33e42602e]

file_name
378996423_1583432815397894_4604468632574713944_n.jpg
file_size
345 kB
file_type
JPEG
file_type_extension
jpg
mime_type
image/jpeg
jfif_version
1.01
resolution_unit
None
x_resolution
72
y_resolution
72
xmp_toolkit
Adobe XMP Core 5.1.2
version
1
directory_item_semantic
Primary
directory_item_mime
image/jpeg
directory_item_length
54828
mpf_version
100
number_of_images
2
mp_image_flags
(none)
mp_image_format
JPEG
mp_image_type
Undefined
mp_image_length
54828
mp_image_start
289682
dependent_image1_entry_number
0
dependent_image2_entry_number
0
image_width
1440
image_height
1800
encoding_process
Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
bits_per_sample
8
color_components
3
y_cb_cr_sub_sampling
YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
image_size
1440x1800
megapixels
2.6
mp_image2
(Binary data 54828 bytes)
category
image

So, I want to get all this metaData and EXIF informations in php.

My function is

```
public static function uploadFileToS3($fileUrl, $resize = true)
    {
        try {
            $data['status'] = false;
            $fileFromUrl = parse_url($fileUrl);
            $fileExt = pathinfo($fileFromUrl['path'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            // $imgSizeArr = get_headers($fileUrl, 1);
            // //$imgSize = round($imgSizeArr["Content-Length"] / 1024, 2); // IN KB
            // $imgSize = $imgSizeArr["Content-Length"]; // IN Bytes

            // if($imgSize < CmnEnum::GOOGLE_GMB_MIN_FILE_SISE) {
            //     Log::error("Image size is too small: " . $imgSize);
            //     return false;
            // }

            $filePath = config('constants.fileStorePath.uploaded') . getCustomEnv('APP_ENV') . '/' . 'intagrams/';
            $uniqueName = date('YmdHis') . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . $fileExt;
            $fileNameWithPath = $filePath . $uniqueName;
            if (!file_exists(public_path($filePath))) {
                \File::makeDirectory(public_path($filePath), 0777, true, true);
            }
            // heicは対応していないためjpegに変換
            Log::debug("THIS IS FILE EXTENTION".print_r($fileExt,TRUE));
            if ($fileExt == 'heic') {
                $fileExt = 'jpeg';
            }
            if ($resize) {
                $resizedImage = Image::make($fileUrl)->resize(CmnEnum::GOOGLE_GMB_RECM_RES_SQUARE, CmnEnum::GOOGLE_GMB_RECM_RES_SQUARE)->encode($fileExt);
                //$compressedImage = compressImage($fileUrl, public_path($fileNameWithPath), 72); // surce image, destination image, resulation 
                $resizedImage->exif();
                $result = Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileNameWithPath, $resizedImage->__toString(), CmnEnum::AWS_S3_VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            } else {
                $result = Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileNameWithPath, Image::make($fileUrl)->encode($fileExt)->__toString(), CmnEnum::AWS_S3_VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            }
            if ($result) {
                $data['status'] = true;
                $data['fileNameWithPath'] = $fileNameWithPath;
                return $data;
            }
            Log::error("Image is not uploaded in s3");
            return $data;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $data['status'] = false;
            writeCustomLog($e);
            Log::error("Image uploading to s3 failed");
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

here,

`$fileUrl = (Link of Published post on Instagram)`

Here I want to detect the Multi-frame image which can be seen in the above information where **number_of_images = 2**.

N.B: I don't/can't install ImageMagick.

Comment: Have you tried [`exif_read_data()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php)?

Comment: yes, But It does not show me the "number_of_images".

Answer (score 0):

Here, After many investigation, I successfully managed to find why the image is generating multiframe images, In the meta data and exif data there is an attribute can be seen known as "number_of_images" by following link : https://www.metadata2go.com/view-metadata

This is occuring by Smart HDR by  Iphone 12pro. https://community.blog2social.com/forum/wordpress/social-networks/google-my-business/3342-update-google-my-business

**Solution**

You can simply just resize the image before posting to GBP with the same aspect ratio.